# How to properly use the Sql Server ROW_NUMBER function with ordered queries?

Tags: sql, sql-server, pagination

I'm trying to understand ROW_NUMBER from MSSQL and making some experiences.

I have these two snippets:

```
SELECT * 
    FROM 
    (
        SELECT *,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (order by p.DtDistribuicao) AS RowNumber
        FROM ProcessoInstanciaFonte as p
    ) as q 

WHERE q.RowNumber BETWEEN 1 AND 20;
```

and

```
select top 20 * from dbo.ProcessoInstanciaFonte as p order by p.DtDistribuicao
```

They both should return the same rows but aren't. What is the problem?

Comment: What differences do you see? One difference is that the first query will have one extra column, and you haven't specified an ORDER to return the rows in (e.g. ORDER BY q.RowNumber) so in theory they could be returned in any order.

Comment: The rows are different. They have different Ids

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I guess that the values of `p.DtDistribuicao` have some ties. The server is free to pick any of the tied values as the "first" one and the two different queries could give two different results in this case.

You could add a unique field at the end of the ORDER BY as a tie-breaker. For example, these two queries should return the same rows (assuming you have a unique field called Id):

```
SELECT * 
    FROM 
    (
        SELECT *,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY p.DtDistribuicao, p.Id) AS RowNumber
        FROM ProcessoInstanciaFonte as p
    ) AS q     
WHERE q.RowNumber BETWEEN 1 AND 20;
ORDER BY q.RowNumber

SELECT TOP 20 *
FROM dbo.ProcessoInstanciaFonte AS p
ORDER BY p.DtDistribuicao, p.Id
```

Comment: Exactly what I was going to write.

Comment: that makes a lot of sense.. I'll try

Comment: If you want to verify that this is the case, change row_number() to dense_rank().  If the resulting query returns more than 20 rows, you have ties and will see exactly where they are (because the ranking function will return the same for them).